# Rails Comparing Latitude/Longitude

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have 1000 objects that have a latitude/longitude value.

What I'd like to do is send up a user's latitude/longitude and return the 50 closest objects. I know how I could do that with one value - if I had just a latitude, but location seems different with the two values so I'm not sure how I'd do that.

What would be the best way to accomplish that? Feel free to point me to a tutorial or anything - I'm very new to using location in rails :).

Comment: check https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails

Comment: also check out geocoder: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder

Comment: The geocoder gem is outstanding. If you watch the execution logs, you'll see how your simple question translates into some advanced calculations, like... [1m[36mLocation Load (93.8ms)[0m  [1mSELECT locations.*, 3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((30.267153 - locations.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(30.267153 * PI() / 180) * COS(locations.latitude * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-97.7430608 - locations.longitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2))) AS distance, MOD(CAST((ATAN2( ((locations.longitude - -97.7430608) / 57.2957795), ((locations.latitude - 30.267153) / 57.2957795)) * 57.2957795)...

Comment: Wow! Never knew it did so much. I'll definitely check out both of those gems

Comment: This doesn't answer the question exactly but if you are using rails, there's a good chance you're using postgres or mysql. If you used postgres GIS or mysql GIS on the data side of things, your calculations would be super efficient and quite easy to sort by closest distance all in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any detail in the original question regarding data representation, but let's suppose you have a list of lat/long values in the form, `[lat, long]` in a list, `locations`. Let's suppose further you have a metric method for the distance between them, `dist(lat, long)`.

Then this will collect all of the location pair combinations and their respective distances as a collection of triples, `[dist, p1, p2]`:

```
location.combination(2).collect { |p| [dist(p[0], p[1]), p[0], p[1]] }
```

You can then sort this which will order by distance, and pick off the top 50:

```
location.combination(2).collect { |p| [dist(p[0], p[1]), p[0], p[1]] }.sort.first(50)
```

You'd have to see if it works with 1,000 objects, as this will create 999,000 combinations initially and I don't know what the Ruby array capacity is.

Comment: This is great - I haven't actually written any of the code yet, just working out the design in my mind first. I think this could definitely be a viable option. At least putting me on the right route!

Comment: @TomHammond I hope it helps. If the number of objects proves too large, then the data will need to be partitioned into smaller groups, and done piece-wise.

Comment: Totally does. Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic computer science problem called the [nearest neighbor problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search). See this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem) for two popular solutions.

The article describes the point with x, y coordinates. You can just substitute longitude for x and latitude for y.

Comment: This is true most of the time. However, when dealing with an ellipsoid earth, the coordinates don't behave like straight lines. Sometimes, the nearest neighbor might be close from a "number" standpoint, but might be over the north pole and not a straight shot, and only true geographic calculations would work.